# Add SSL certificate from Godaddy to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to add an SSL certificate that I created on Godaddy to my Google App Engine account on a Mac.

Using Keychain, I created a new 2048bit RSA private-public key pair, and with it created a `CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest`. I then used this certificate signing request to create the new SSL certificate on Godaddy. They then let me download a zip file with two `.crt` files in it (`734b34####.crt` and `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`).

And then trying to add it to GAE, I get this screen:

[image: Add new SSL certificate screen on GAE]

Can anyone tell me what to enter as "PEM encoded X.509 public key certificate" and what as "Unexcrypted PEM encoded RSA private key"?

I tried exporting from Keychain all different relevant keys and certificates in all kinds of format (`p12`, `cer`, and converting them to `pem`), even without passwords on them.

For some reason, whenever I export & convert the private key, its beginning looks like this:

`Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: *.mydomain.com
    localKeyID: 10 93 42 BE 45...
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.mydomain.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After not finding any guide to do it on a Mac, and trying different options for hours, here's what I did:

1. Concat the two `.crt` provided by Godaddy into one: `cat 734b34####.crt gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > godaddy.crt`.
2. Use `godaddy.crt` for the first certificate ("PEM encoded X.509 public key certificate").
3. In Keychain, export (without a password) the private key that was used for the certificate signing request in `p12` format, let's call it `private.p12`:
   [image]
4. Convert the `p12` private key: `openssl pkcs12 -in private.p12 -out private.pem -nodes -clcerts`. The password is just empty.
5. [EDIT] - then convert the `private.pem` file to RSA type: `openssl rsa -in private.pem -out private_unencrypted.pem -outform PEM`
6. Copy the contents of the created file: `pbcopy < private_unencrypted.pem`.
7. Paste (what we've just copied) into the second text area ("Unecrypted PEM encoded RSA private key").
8. <s>Edit the pasted text, so that all of the text starting from `Bag Attributes` until `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` (excluding) is deleted. The result is a long string that starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.</s>

You should now be able to click the Upload button at the bottom.

Phew!

Would love to see if anyone had a more elegant / official way to do it.